# Pause and Restart projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build-process, build-automation, jenkins-plugins, buildforge

Is there a way I can manually pause a running project in Jenkins between different build steps, and then restart it later? (The feature I am asking is similar to the one we have in buildforge.)

Answer (score 0):

No.  Not as of the current version, Jenkins 1.479.